# Have settings launcher in plank? (preferibly by default)

Tags: system, plank

I wonder if may be possible to create a launcher in plank, with the program icon itself, to run the setting manager. Might it be possible?

Right now, only way to access settings in typing in a terminal 
`plank --preferences`

Or, once hovering the mouse cursor over that dock, pressing ctrl + right mouse click. A launcher would simplyfy this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need. Just do `Ctrl + Right Click` over the dock and select preferences.

If you still want to add the icon to launch preferences, then copy the plank launcher (located in `/usr/share/applications`) into your personal app folder (`~/.local/share/applications`) and edit the desktop file. Modify the line that says `execute = plank` by  `execute = plank --preferences` and you will have the launcher you are looking for. Change the permissions (chmod +x `~/.local/share/applications/plank.desktop`) and drag it into the dock. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to find a spot but if you can right click on an empty spot on plank and select preferences.  The easiest spot I found is like right on the border of the right side.

Alternatively you could create a bash script and simply drag it onto plank I guess but how often do you really need to edit it?

Comment: just do ctrl + right click

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I know, another way may be to open the settings file in the current dock config:

`/home/user.config/plank/dock1/settings`

and editing the following line:

`#Whether to show the item for the dock itself. 
ShowDockItem=false`

changing the parameter `false` to `true`, but it do not work!  Maybe it's that particular version of plank used by eOS,but I don't see wht it's so hard to implement it :/

PS:  i've read somewhere that the official name is Pantheon Dock, is that true?

Comment: Ok, so creating a launcher, written in first post, and dragging it to the dock is indeed the best solution, but please i'd like to ask developers: why eOS users cannot have it already by default?

Comment: The official software is called Plank, not Pantheon Dock.